# Changing Linux swap partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, ubuntu-10.04, swap

I want to change the swap partition to another partition. Is there a gui that can make this process easier so I don't have to do things like manually editing files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in case you don't find a GUI method, you will find the terminal method quite flexible and easy. Run the following commands:

```
sudo swapoff /dev/hda3
sudo mkswap /dev/hda4
sudo swapon /dev/hda4
```

Then update /etc/fstab. Change the line containing "/dev/hda3" to "/dev/hda4".

Here is the [Ubuntu page on Swap FAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq). Also note (from that page):
`With the 2.6 kernel, "a swap file is just as fast as a swap partition."`
<sup>Which means that you don't need to lock down a partition for swap space; you can tune it locally in a data partition as a swap-file.</sup>

Comment: You know, not everybody likes the terminal.

Comment: @Lord.Quackstar, yes I agree. Have changed the start of my answer to indicate its usefulness in the event a clean GUI is not found `':-)`'.

Answer (score 2):

Use **Parted Magic LiveCD**. Download it from [here](http://download.cnet.com/Parted-Magic-LiveCD/3000-2094_4-10663999.html), burn it to a CD and go.

Comment: I think the OP already has the partition, just needs to change swap.

Comment: I guess awakeFromNib does not need to worry about command line tools. Actually, command line tools for non frequent tasks (like partitioning) are easy to forget